# Is it possible to recursively change key names with jq using the with_entries method?

Tags: jq

Let's say I have the following JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "name1": "fruits",
    "name2": "cars",
    "name3": "houses"
  }
]
```

I know I can use `jq` for renaming its values like the following:

```
jq '[.[] | .["newname1"] = .name1 | del(.name1)]' file
```

This works fine and it allows me to do changes even on more complex JSON structures... However, that's a very explicit declaration of the keys that I want to change. An alternative way of doing the same thing would be with the command:

```
jq 'map(with_entries(if .key == "name1" then .key = "newname1" else . end))' file
```

This is a way of checking all keys with specific names inside a JSON that is an Array of Objects and changing them. I don't need to explicitly declare the name of the `key` in this case. However, this works only on an Array of Objects. I'd like to find a way of changing all keys inside a json like that in an recursive way. Let's say I have a JSON like the following one:

```
{
  "name1": "one",
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "name1": "one",
      "valueA": "0",
      "valueB": "0",
      "keyB": "2",
      "keyC": "3"
    },
    {
      "name1": "two",
      "valueA": "11",
      "valueB": "21",
      "keyB": "15",
      "keyC": "20"
    }
  ]
}
```

My last `jq` command doesn't work on this JSON. Is there any way of changing all `name1` keys recursively using `jq`? Perhaps finding a way of using `recurse(.[]?;true)` together with this command? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```bsh
jq 'walk(if type == "object" then with_entries( if .key == "name1" then .key = "newname1" else . end ) else . end)' file
```

This is more or less straight from the `jq` manual (the section describing the `walk()` function).  The `walk()` function acts like a "recursive `map()`" and the only thing that we need to be careful about is to check the type of the entity that we're currently dealing with.

Using `walk()`, you may also apply the first approach of yours:

```bsh
jq 'walk(if type == "object" and has("name1") then ( .newname1 = .name1 | del(.name1) ) else . end)' file
```

This does however place the `newname1` key last in each object rather than replace `name1` in the position where it was found (if that matters).

Another approach (with `jq` 1.6) is to use the recursive decent operator `..`, selecting anything that has the key we're looking for, and then updating those objects:

```bsh
jq '(.. | select(has("name1")?)) |= with_entries(if .key == "name1" then .key = "newname1" else . end)' file
```

Comment: Cool, in my case I'm using jq 1.5 yet... So in order for the last command to work, I need to substitute the recursive decent operator `..` to `recurse(.[]?;true)`... After this change, it works fine... My feeling is that your last sample gives more possibilities for solving different kind of problems so I'll try to expand from it here... Thanks

Comment: @raylight Good! I'm a bit hazy on what's new in 1.6 (which is what I'm using) as I've been mostly using this version to learn the tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me so much after scratching my head for hours on how to filter or replace keys!